# need to compare item from first list to every other item in second list and return pass or fail for each check in new list

Tags: python, list

i have two lists

```
lsitA = [100,200,300]
listB = [[97,103],[103,202],[202,250]]
```

i'm trying to check if item in `listA[x]` is within a certain margin from `listB[i][0]` or `listB[i][1]`
then return false, else return true. in other words i'm trying to see if `lsitA[0]` meets these condition either for `listB[1]` or `listB[2]` or `listB[3]`, then return False. number of True/False must be equal to number of sub-lists in `listB`

this is what i have tried so far

```
lsitA = [100,200,300]
listB = [[97,103],[103,202],[202,250]]

def check(listB, val):
    result = []  
    
    for x in range(len(listB)):
        if listB[x][0]<=val<=listB[x][0]+4 or listB[x][1]-4<=val<=listB[x][1]:
            return result.append(print('Fail')) 
    return result.append(print('Pass'))

for i in lsitA:
    check(listB,i)

##Expected output: [Fail,Fail,Pass]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask]. I haven't read your code, but I'm inferring it doesn't work like you want it to. So what do you need help with exactly?

Comment: `return result.append(print('Fail'))` seems to be wrong in four different ways: 1) `print()` always returns `None`; 2) `list.append()` always returns `None`; 3) If you `return` from inside the loop, `len(result)` may be less than `len(listB)`; 4) `result` is never returned.

Comment: BTW, `lsitA` seems to be a typo

Comment: I have updated the question to add more context and expected output. by margin i mean i am trying to check if any element within the listA exists within +=(some number) from elements in listB. Also i'm not sure how to make it return in the way i want it to

Comment: Your code is already giving you the output. Just need to append it to a list or list comprehension. `[check(listB, i) for i in lsitA]`

Comment: i'm not getting output as i want. my output is like `Fail  Fail  Pass` in 3 separate lines. i'm not getting a list @KevinChoonLiangYew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result.append()` Returns nothing, and so does `print()`.
If you want a list containing the result, I suggest doing the followings:

```py
def check(listB, val):
    for item in listB:
        if val in range(item[0], item[1]+1):
            return 'Fail'
    return 'Pass'

result = [check(listB, i) for i in listA]
```

Comment: Be aware that `range` only works if the value is integer.

Comment: If the numbers inside listB are not integers, you may use `if item[0] <= val <= item[1]:`, which works for floats also.

Comment: is there any way to make this run faster? the actual data i have has 1M entries in both lists and it is taking forever to output @kelvinC